# Creating a User List for a Chat Program GUI

Tags: java

I have three programs that work together to make a chat room. I have a server, handler and client. I am attempting to have a constant list of online users in the GUI, so if a new client joined the chat they could still see the list of users. This list is a visible list function in the GUI. I have created and array list in the chat handler, but I have no idea how to have the list appear in the GUI. Please help me, I am a beginner.

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatServer{
  Socket s;
  ArrayList<ChatHandler>handlers;
  public ChatServer(){
try{
  ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2020);
  handlers = new ArrayList<ChatHandler>();
  for(;;){
s = ss.accept();//wait for a new client to connect
new ChatHandler(s, handlers).start();// spawn a handler for client
  }
}catch(IOException ioe){
  System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
}
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
ChatServer tes = new ChatServer(); 
  }

}
```

Handler code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatHandler extends Thread{
  Socket s;
  BufferedReader br;
  PrintWriter pw;
  String temp;
  ArrayList<ChatHandler>handlers;
  String nickName;
  List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()

  public ChatHandler(Socket s, ArrayList<ChatHandler>handlers){
    this.s = s;
    this.handlers = handlers;
    this.nickName = nickName;
  }


  public void run(){
    try{
      handlers.add(this);// add myself to list
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
      pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
      temp = "";
      System.out.println("Enter a username: ");
      nickName = br.readLine();
      myList.add(nickName);
      System.out.println(nickName+" joined the chat!");
      while((temp = br.readLine()) != null){
        for (ChatHandler ch : handlers){// broadcast to all clients
             ch.pw.println(nickName+":"+" "+temp); //tell each handler in turn to send message to its client
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
      }
    }catch(IOException ioe){
      System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());      
    }finally{
      handlers.remove(this);//remove myself from list
    }
  }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatFrame extends Frame{
    public ChatFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Chatting with myself");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ChatPanel sp = new ChatPanel();
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ChatFrame sf = new ChatFrame();
    }
}

class ChatPanel extends Panel implements ActionListener, Runnable{
    Thread t;
    TextField tf;
    TextArea ta;
    List lst;
    Button b;
    Socket s;
BufferedReader br;
PrintWriter pw;
String temp;
boolean connected;

public ChatPanel(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tf = new TextField();
    tf.addActionListener(this);
    add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ta = new TextArea();
    add(ta, BorderLayout.WEST);
    lst = new List();
    add(lst, BorderLayout.EAST);
    b = new Button("Connect");
    b.addActionListener(this);
    add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    //t = new Thread(this);
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    if((ae.getSource() == b) && (!connected)){
        try{
            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2020);
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
            System.out.println(uhe.getMessage());
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        connected = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        //b.setEnabled(false);
        b.setLabel("Disconnect");
        t.start();
    }else if((ae.getSource() == b) && (connected)){
        connected = false;
        try{
            s.close(); //no buffering so, ok
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        //System.exit(0);
        b.setLabel("Connect");
    }else{
        temp = tf.getText();
        pw.println(temp);
        tf.setText("");
    }
}
public void run(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        ta.append("Please enter a username"+"\n");
        while(((temp = br.readLine()) != null) && connected){
            ta.append(temp + "\n");
            temp = "";


    }}catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'll just leave this here, as it's very useful in problems like yours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
public ChatFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Chatting with myself");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        ChatPanel sp = new ChatPanel();
        add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new JList(YouArrayList.toArray() , BorderLayout.EAST) ; 
        setVisible(true);
    }
```

I assume your ArrayList has the user correctly. 
also you can refer to JList post https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Comment: How would you add to this list an inputted username?

Comment: I think you may be do some thing like making you list as static in the ChatHandler and then refer to it when the connection happen, or finished in your chat panel, you need to add setter and getter to it in the ChatPanel in your frame tou can say cp.getMyUserList().toArray();

Answer (score 0):

You need four methods in order to achieve your goal: (1) An ArrayList to hold all nicknames. (2) An Accessor (getter) to fetch your nickname list into your GUI. (3) A Mutator (Setter) to add onto the Array of nicknames. (4) A method to remove or update nicknames from the Array if they disconnect from the chat.

Summary; you need to create three methods and a List in the Server code. You will call these methods in your Client code as needed. You will also need an instance of the Server whenever you want access its methods from outside its class. See below code and use as a reference.

```
//Adds nickname to myList
public void AddUserName(String name){
    myList.add(name);
}

//Removes disconnected nicknames from myList
public void RemoveUserName(String name){
    for( int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++ ){
        if(myList(i) == name){
        myList.remove(i);
        }
    }
}

//Returns all nicknames in myList
public ArrayList getUsersOnline(){
    return usersOnline;
}
```

So in your Client code, you will write something like this: cs.getUsersOnline();. You may also need to loop through and append to your list on the Client side. For example see below:

```
for(int i=0; i < myList.size(); i++){
    list.add(ArrayList(i));
}
```

I hope I'm able to help.